# How do I annotate @NamedEntityGraph for a composite entity for hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to the concept of hibernate and JPA. I've learned that it is benefit to use `@NamedEntityGraph` for initializing the relationship.

However, I am having trouble in annotating `@NamedEntityGraph` to an entity with composite structure.

Here is a part of my code, it is a Kanban management system.

I have an entity `Workflow`, with a field `lanes` which is a set of `Lane`.

```
@Entity
public class Workflow {
    @ManyToMany(
            cascade =
                    {
                            CascadeType.DETACH,
                            CascadeType.MERGE,
                            CascadeType.REFRESH,
                            CascadeType.PERSIST
                    },
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "rootstage_in_workflow",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "lane_id")})
    @OrderBy("order")
    private final Set<Lane> lanes;
}
```

The class `Lane` presents a *composite* structure, with a field `children`, which is a set of children lanes.

```
@Entity
public class Lane {
    @ManyToMany(
            cascade =
                    {
                            CascadeType.DETACH,
                            CascadeType.MERGE,
                            CascadeType.REFRESH,
                            CascadeType.PERSIST
                    },
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("order")
    private final Set<Lane> children;
}
```

I have tried to add the following to Workflow:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "Kanban.Aggregate.Workflow",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "lanes", subgraph = "lane"),
        subgraphs = {
                @NamedSubgraph(
                        name = "lane",
                        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("children")
                )
        }
)
```

However it seems not working, and I get the following error message while getting children from a lane:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: <package>.Lane.children, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I have also try the following:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "Kanban.Aggregate.Workflow",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "lanes", subgraph = "lane"),
        subgraphs = {
                @NamedSubgraph(
                        name = "lane",
                        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value="children", subgraph = "lane")
                )
        }
)
```

But I get a stack overflow error.

Could anyone tell me how to use the annotation for describing such composite object?

Comment: You have Lane->Children->Lane as a circular reference in your graph with no end to the graph. Why are you trying to fetch the children of the workflow's lanes exactly? And why do you need their children as well? Some other providers might be able to handle this better, but you are likely better off not trying to go that far in the entity graph - stop at 'lanes' and manually trigger their children in the query results.

Comment: @Chris maybe I have misunderstood about the entity graph. I added the entity graph to avoid the N+1 select issue, but I am not really sure if this is a correct way to do it.